# Get data from Chrome Custom Tab request URL in Android

Tags: java, android, paypal, braintree, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to implement a PayPal Vault Braintree payment solution. But since it is a "redirect" process via Chrome Custom Tab, I am having trouble finishing the process. This because in Paypal Web version, the "data response" returns in URL to be used. However, on Android I cannot achieve the same result since the Chrome Custom Tab Works in parallel to the application.

The documentation talks about some listeners that are supposed to work automatically and also about some handlers that can be added manually. However, I don't know how to trigger these listeners and I was also unable to implement a "response" in the handlers.

For now I can open the PayPal page and finish the authentication and authorization, but I do now know how to get data from response.
Anyway, any help would be cool.

Thank you.

The function opening the Chorm Custom tab:

```
public void startBillingAgreement() {
    PayPalRequest request = new PayPalRequest()
            .localeCode("US")
            .billingAgreementDescription("Your agreement description");

    PayPal.requestBillingAgreement(getBraintreeFragment(), request);
}
```

[The process guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/vault/android/v3) (they say about the onPaymentMethodNonceCreated function, but i do not know how to)

[The listeners guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v3)